# php Form submit error 500

Tags: php

I have a problem with a simple form submit, for personal use and testing.
Unfortunately I do not have access on the server to see logs or set error reporting but I've tried to do it in my PHP code like this:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

So I have this form:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="check_login.php">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
    <input type="username" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required autofocus>
    <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

And this code to validate it:

```
$login = array('example' => '3f76d6c6b8aa132e8306a0b4e6e02916',
    'another' => 'ef872ac2466ca845aa0547e02554d7e1',
    'alsoexample' => '3b3efb7345b89c6bbef71e5b6f257426');

if ($login[$_POST['username']] == md5($_POST['password'])) {
    $_SESSION['user']='logged';
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

But as soon as I hit the submit button it returns a 500 error.
What am I doing wrong?
I've looked a lot after errors but I can't find. Many many thanks if someone can help me!

Comment: what are you trying to do with following line -> if ($login[$_POST['username']] == md5($_POST['password'])) {

Comment: its might be something wrong with .htaccess

Comment: What does `check_login.php` look like exactly, did you put the error reporting statements there? Also, don't use `header` redirects while you are trying to find the problem.

Comment: error_reporting(-1); is it correct -1 instead 1 ?

Comment: Are you sure you can just reach check_login.php from the form? as Dyvesh stated, your .htcaccess configuration could prevent you to access/routing that uri just by the filename. The first you should do is try to return a custom OK response from the check_login.php file, without any login check and redirect headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code on my server and it worked.

Is there more code above the part you shared? I think something there causes a 500 error.

It also could be possible that `header('location: ')` doens't work because the headers are allready send.

Try to replace it with this to see if that causes the error:

```
echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace("/index.php")</script>';
echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace("/login.php")</script>';
```

Comment: There is just a bit of html code that I did not post, nothing to worry about though. I will check and come back with an answer, thank you!

Comment: Thank you! This was the root of all my problems!

Comment: No problem, im glad i could help you ;)